# Replace specific column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tissues':['a1','x2','y3','b','c1','v2','w3'], 'M':[1,2,'a',4,'b','a',7]})
df.set_index('Tissues')
```

The dataframe looks like:

```
         M
Tissues   
a1       1
x2       2
y3       a
b        4
c1       b
v2       a
w3       7
```

How can I replace all `a`s in column `M` with say a specific value, 2 and all `b`s to 3?

I tried:

```
replace_values = {'a':2, 'b':3}
df['M'] = df['M'].map(replace_values)
```

, but that changed other values not in the keys in `replace_values` to `NaN`:

```
  Tissues    M
0      a1  NaN
1      x2  NaN
2      y3  2.0
3       b  NaN
4      c1  3.0
5      v2  2.0
6      w3  NaN
```

I see that I can do

```
df.loc[(df['M'] == 'a')] = 2
```

but can I do this efficiently for a, b and so on, instead of one by one?

Comment: Your own solution was perfectly fine, just missed `fillna`, replace last line with: `df['M'] = df['M'].map(replace_values).fillna(df['M'])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tissues':['a1','x2','y3','b','c1','v2','w3'], 'M':[1,2,'a',4,'b','a',7]})
df.set_index('Tissues')

replace_values = {'a':2, 'b':3}

df['M'] = df['M'].replace(replace_values)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df
  Tissues  M
0      a1  1
1      x2  2
2      y3  2
3       b  4
4      c1  3
5      v2  2
6      w3  7
```

Answer (score 4):

Fix your code by add `fillna`

```
df['M'] = df['M'].map(replace_values).fillna(df.M)
df
  Tissues    M
0      a1  1.0
1      x2  2.0
2      y3  2.0
3       b  4.0
4      c1  3.0
5      v2  2.0
6      w3  7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.replace`

```
replace_values = {'a':2, 'b':3}
df = df.replace({"M": replace_values})
```

Results:

```
Tissues  M
0      a1  1
1      x2  2
2      y3  a
3       b  4
4      c1  b
5      v2  a
6      w3  7
```